# Can someone help me to fix the betting, I can't bet on other game match_id once I bet on a match

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

Thi is the full smart contract:https://github.com/laronlineworld/betMatch/blob/main/betMatch.sol

This is betting contract, when betting on id_1, the same address can't bet on id_2.
I'm using Game storage

```
function bet(uint _gameId, uint8 _teamSelected) public payable {
  Game storage game = gameInfo[_gameId];
  require(game.state == State.Created,"Game has not been created");
  require(bettingActive);
  //The first require is used to check if the player already exist
  require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender));
  //The second one is used to see if the value sended by the player is
  //Higher than the minimum value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);

  //We set the player informations : amount of the bet and selected team
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].teamSelected = _teamSelected;

  //then we add the address of the player to the players array
  players.push(msg.sender);

  //at the end, we increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
  if ( _teamSelected == 1){
      totalBetsOne += msg.value;
  }
  else{
      totalBetsTwo += msg.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to pick another account to excute bet() with id_2

Comment: it works with other address, but it needs to bet on different matches.

Comment: it seems that you have to distributePrizes the first game, then you can bet on next game

Comment: that's a nice idea thank you, but the process on betting is user address can bet on different matches using 1 address at the same time.

Comment: I just went through the whole code. In my view, if you bet on differet matches, it will overwrite the playerInfo[msg.sender].

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do exactly, are you trying to bet on 2 different games with the same address? If so are you the creator of the contract? Because the code is filled with things that prevent you to do so, and it seems very intentionnal to me.

```
//The first require is used to check if the player already exist
  require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender));
```

This is only one example and probably the most obvious one

Comment: Is there a solution to bet on other match?